# TensorFlow sees a black screen as an object for 99%

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I have the problem that TensorFlow detects a black screen as an object?
I have trained it so it only can see two classes, but I want to see N/A label if its neither the classes.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg9om.png)

Hope you guys have any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what code you're using, but I assume your classes are truth or lying from faces. Two suggestions:

- It may be that you have divided your image data by 255 twice at some point.
- Make sure you include a third class which is "not a face". I assume you're passing your convolutional neural network model round each pixel of an image. It can't classify a table as lying or telling the truth, so make sure a "not considered" class is predicted for things that aren't faces.